# 3D Symbology for a Model Farm in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, visualisation, arcscene, 3d-model

I am working on visualization of a model farm I have developed consisting of various types of grazing land, cropping areas and other. As I have constructed it myself, I don't have an image with it for display. I am looking for symbology options I can use in ArcScene to give it a realistic touch. I have tried to use picture but it doesn't work well. Here, the screenshots below shows the things I've tried with 3D texture fill sumbol and picture fill symbol. I don't have many options in the texture one and it looks all the same if I use the grass1 or grass2 as symbols for grazing or cropping land. As this is a created farm, not an actual one on earth, so I obviously don't have any aerial images or satellite images for the farm area, which would have been great, therefore, I am not sure how I can make it look real. I want to make a fly over animation from this once I make it look more real. I have draped a DEM on the farm landscape in ArcScene. Any ideas?

[image: Farm Landscape]

[image: Farm Landscape with Elevation data in ArcScene]

[image: 3D textures available]

[image: Result of using 3D texture]

[image: Using Picture as Symbology]

[image: Result of Picture Symbology]

Comment: What do you mean by 3D symbology? Your second image appears to have draped your land use classification over a DEM. Are you looking for realistic textures to use instead of the flat colors used in the current symbology? Or are you wanting a current aerial/sat photo of the area which you can still see with your land use classification on top of it? Can you provide a screenshot of what you tried and didn't like?

Comment: Thanks Chris, you made my day again.......Yes I wanted to increase the size of the tile and by increasing the value in x and y, it worked! It looks more real now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is partially going to be a function of scale. Depending on the scale of your map, any given texture might look incorrect because of the pattern/detail it's trying to represent. Easiest to see just by going to Google maps and turning on sat imagery and zooming in and out and noting how crops just become a blur. In your example, if you like the individual tile but not the grid pattern it produces, try upping the x and y scale in the dialog box you show in your last image. That controls how big a single tile is, so with fewer (or one) tiles you may get the effect you want.

You could also go onto Google maps (or other imagery) and locate a land pattern you like, perhaps even at the right scale to match your map, screenshot it and crop it to a square tile, and use that instead of the included textures - also playing with the texture tile scale. Note that if you use this method it can be tricky getting a pattern that tiles together nicely without obvious seams (as evidenced in your first attempt there).